# How to setup default editor for Eclipse Remote System Explorer?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How do you assign or setup the default editor for opened file using Eclipse Remote System Explorer?  I need to use Eclipse's editor itself. Thanks.

Comment: Eclipse has more than one editor. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: the python editor